# Confusion about the select module in Python

Tags: python, select

I am a little confused about the select module in python. As [PyMOTW](https://pymotw.com/2/select/) describes:

> select monitors sockets, open files, and pipes (anything with a
>   fileno() method that returns a valid file descriptor) until they
>   become readable or writable, or a communication error occurs.

I am confused about what do readable and writable mean? What's the difference between them?

Besides, it describes:

> select() returns three new lists, containing subsets of the contents
>   of the lists passed in. All of the sockets in the readable list have
>   incoming data buffered and available to be read. All of the sockets in
>   the writable list have free space in their buffer and can be written
>   to. The sockets returned in exceptional have had an error (the actual
>   definition of “exceptional condition” depends on the platform).

So in my understanding, the select module is such a tool which monitors multiple sockets when they are open and working. Select can tell a specific socket whether it should read the data, write data or there is an error. Is that right? Could someone explain to me that how does it achieve multi-connection socket communication?

Comment: Read Amadan's answer and play around with an asyncio client/server and think about how it works https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tcp_echo.html

Answer (score 1):

`select` doesn't tell sockets anything. It just watches them.

Say you have a building with one entrance. You post a receptionist there. He watches the door, and when there's someone at the door, he goes and opens the door for the guest.

Now you build a back entrance, but you are too cheap to hire a second receptionist. So while the front receptionist is staring at the front entrance, the back entrance is piling up with very angry people staring at the stubbornly closed door.

If only there was a surveillance system, so that the poor receptionist could see both doors at the same time...

That's what `select` does.

Normally when you `f.read()` (on a blocking file descriptor), your program stops till some data shows up. When you `f.write()` but the other side has signalled their buffer is full, your program will stop till the other end clears some space in their buffer and signals it's okay to receive again. And when your program is stuck on some IO operation, it can't do anything else - while incoming data in other sockets is piling up, or maybe while a user on some other socket is impatiently waiting for their response.

With `select`, it waits until *any* file descriptor has something you can do about. It will wait until something becomes actionable; then it will tell you where `f.read` will be instantaneously responded to, and where `write` will be instantly sent, without further blocking.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But I still have a little question about what you said. Let's make an assumption, there are two sockets `A` and `B`. Now socket `A` is supposed to read the data transited from socket `B`, but `A` doesn't think there is data from `B`. so `A` just blocks itself. However, if we use select, `A` will be notified immediately when there is data from `B` waiting to be read. So as a result, `A` can read the data without any unnecessary blocking. Am I right?

Comment: If A and B are sockets, they are independent and mindless - I can't think of what you could be referring to when you say "`A` doesn't think there is data from `B`". The most simple scenario is just running `select` on your reads, to know who to process next, and ignoring the fact that write could block. If you have `users[10]` and each user has their own socket, you can't be reading all of them, you'd be blocked most of the time. `select` allows you to see who sent something so you can respond.